# Displaying form and button next to each other on w3css

Tags: html, css, forms, button, w3.css

I am using w3.css in my codeiniter project and I want to put them next to each other.

Here is my code:

```
<a type="button" class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-pull-left" href="http://localhost/cblog/posts/ikkinchi-post">Tahrirlash</a> 
<form action="http://localhost/cblog/posts/delete/2" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="submit" value="O`chirish" class="w3-btn w3-red">
</formm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have type="button" attribute on your link?

To display the elements on one line change their style to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Or if you don't need padding

```
display:inline;
```

So it will look like this

```
a,form{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it is not answer ((

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: i was pretty dumb 

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_display.asp) for W3.css and see if there's a class that will make an element display inline and maybe use the classes designed for navigation bars. If there's not, then you can create a class yourself and assign it to the element you wish.

`.displayInline { display: inline;}`